# Issue while plotting single channeled images (e.g. grayscale) using imshow

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

While plotting single channel image (i.e. while plotting grayscale images) when using Python it does not plot in gray-scale.

Example: expected output, after converting a coloured image using COLOR_BGR2GRAY from open cv :

[image]

But, the output obtained is:

[image]

Can anyone help me find out, what is the exact issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon researching, I found out that, the issue is actually not with open cv, but it is with matplotlib package. While displaying the image, the matplotlib package uses a colormap and hence it has to be explicitly set to gray, using :

```
plt.imshow(image, cmap="gray")
```